# Consulta join laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Tengo el siguiente problema, al realizar una consulta no se como puedo restringir a que solo aparezca el primer dato parecido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, gonzales dexy me aparece mas de una vez ya que esos datos vienen de un join como el siguiente:

```
    $alumnos=Alumno::join('alumno_plan_nivel', 'alumno_plan_nivel.id_alumno', '=', 'alumno.id_alumno')
    ->where('alumno.cat_situacion_alumno_id_cat_situacion_alumno', '=','2')
        ->paginate(10);
```

En la tabla: alumno_plan_nivel ella se repite, lo que quisiera hacer es tomar solamente el primer valor de gonzales dexy. Ya intente con take(1) y solo trae uno de toda mi consulta pero quisiera hacerlo solo en id_alumno parecido.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Ya probaste agregar un `select` donde meter las columnas exactas que deseas recuperar y luego con un `groupBy` agrupar por todas esas mismas columnas?

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con un `->first()` el cual de devuelve el primer valor que encuentre en la DB con esos datos

```
$alumnos=Alumno::join('alumno_plan_nivel', 'alumno_plan_nivel.id_alumno', '=', 'alumno.id_alumno')
->where('alumno.cat_situacion_alumno_id_cat_situacion_alumno', '=','2')
    ->first();
```

Comment: Ya esta arreglado